# Does QPID C++ client support SSL channel encryption with RabbitMQ broker

Tags: c++, encryption, rabbitmq, qpid

I am evaluating multiple C/C++ clients for RabbitMQ mesasging broker. We have gone through SimpleAmqpClient, AMQP-CPP and now evaluating Apache QPID. The deployment setup contains a RabbitMQ broker v3.6.12(with rabbitmq-amqp1.0 plugin enabled) and a QPID C++ client.

Does QPID C++ client support SSL based channel encryption and also authentication to the broker? I have gone through the documentation but I did not find a concrete example of SSL based channel encryption using QPID C++ client. However, I found examples for Java clients.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the Qpid Proton C++ API.  There's another C++ API at Qpid called "Qpid Messaging", but Proton is the better choice for new work.

The Qpid APIs in general support SSL encryption, often by using a connection URL with an "amqps:" scheme, or sometimes by setting a connection option.  The Proton C++ API uses the former approach.

```
struct your_handler : public proton::messaging_handler { 
    void on container_start(proton::container& cont) override {
        cont.connect("amqps://example.org");
    }
};
```

Here are some Proton C++ examples that address more advanced SSL scenarios:

http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.22.0/proton/cpp/examples/ssl.cpp.html
http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.22.0/proton/cpp/examples/ssl_client_cert.cpp.html